# close the previous parent menu when click on the submenu of the other parent menu(but both of the parent menu should be able to stay open)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is the jQuery part: I need to make it able to stay open the previous Menu when I press on the other Menu; here is the Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ntqosb9f/

And if it's possible: close the previous Menu when I click on submenu of the last opened Menu.

```
$(".sidenav_active").parent().css({
  "display": "block"
});

$('ul.navbar-nav li').click(function () {
  $('.sidenav_wrapper:visible').add(
    $(this).find('.sidenav_wrapper:first')
  ).toggle();   
});
```

Comment: "I need to make it able to stay open the previous Menu when I press on the other Menu". Well, it is already happening. What is the issue exactly?

Comment: hi  Azametzin, I just fixed it in Fiddle. The posted JS+jquery code was the initially wrong one. Thanks for answering!